# Convert Sqlserver to Mysql server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

*Hello All,*

*I am creating trigger into the MySql Aurora but I want Error Handling into Trigger* 
**For Example**

```
Update WorkA
Set grpId= select(g.GroupID)  -- Getting Error in this line
From   WorkA luGroup g 
Where  typeWrd=g.GroupName
AND    g.GroupTypeId= v_gtid;
If RETURNED_SQLSTATE <> 0      -- Getting Error in this line 
Then
Signal  SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 50002 11, 1, 'trInluDivision';
End if;


Sql Server code


   Update @workA 
      Set grpId = g.GroupId
     From @workA, luGroup g
    Where typeWrd = g.GroupName  
      and g.GroupTypeId = @gtid
```

Actually,I am stuck
Please help on this that will be very helpful

Thanks
Aman

Comment: So basically you asking help to convert a SQL Server trigger code into MySQL trigger code? Where is SQL server trigger code? Where are you stuck are there errors?

Comment: What MySQL version do you use? Use `SELECT VERSION()` to find out.

Comment: You can edit ( https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51480277/edit )  your question.. Dont place code in comment to update the question information..

Comment: Set    grpId=g.GroupID  is invalid should be Set    grpId=(select g.GroupID...),  From   WorkA luGroup g  is invalid - is this supposed to be some sort of join or is it one table with a space in the name you are aliasing as g?

Comment: yes , i am aliasing as g of lugroup table

Comment: I am getting error into this line "Set grpId= select(g.GroupID)", please check

Comment: 'i am aliasing as g of lugroup table'  -  so whats worka then and the set should look a bit like this Set    grpId=(select g.GroupID   # Getting Error in this line
From   WorkA_luGroup g 
Where  typeWrd=g.GroupName
AND    g.GroupTypeId= v_gtid
); Oh and comments in mysql start with a #

Comment: Worka is the Temporary table in my case

Comment: Well what are you trying to do with worka - what you have is not a valid join

Comment: i added the Sql server join into the Question , please correct me on this

Comment: You haven't copied the from statement correctly (you are missing the comma) btw you shouldn't be using implicit joins anyway